# How to scan Lora E32-TTL-100 devices by using only one ESP 8266 + Lora E32-TTL-100s?

Tags: arduino-esplora

I'm investigating for some function of Lora E32-TTL-100.
Currently, I can communicate between two E32 like the following image:
[image]
But 3 days ago, I saw a person used only one MCU to scan the other E32 is power-on or power-off:
[image]
It's so interesting, and tried many way, but wasn't successful.
I found many documents but they always mention communicate 2 MCUs + 2 Loras.

Again, the purpose is how to do for the 1st E32 know that the 2nd E32 is power-on.
Can anyone please help me with it or have any ideas about it?

This's the link I followed https://www.mischianti.org/2019/11/10/lora-e32-device-for-arduino-esp32-or-esp8266-fixed-transmission-part-4/

This is the schema to simulate it:
[image: schema]
Thank.

Comment: please post a link to what you saw 3 days ago

Comment: @jsotola, I saw my teacher done it like the above images. We will know that the 2nd is power-off, the 2nd, 3rd E32 is power-on. I'm not sure about how to implement it. I also ask my teacher, but he said that I should find the solutions for it. but no hope.